# Is it possible to change the x- and y-axis caption dynamically with the vaadin addon InvientCharts

Tags: java, visualization, vaadin, add-on, scatter-plot

I am using vaadin and for some visual data analysis I've added the addon InvientCharts for vaadin (https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/invient-charts).

**Is it possible to dynamically change the x- and y-axis Caption of the scattertchart (so after the chart has been created)?**

I'm currently having a scatterchart and a button. When the button is clicked, all existing points (Series) shall be removed, the x- and y-axis caption shall change and the new points shall be added on the chart.

That's the code snippet with which I'm trying it currently:

```
public void changePoints(String xAxisTitle, String yAxisTitle, List<List<double[]>> xAndYCoordinates) {
        // remove all points from the scatterchart - THIS IS WORKING
        Object[] allSeries = chart.getAllSeries().toArray();
        for(int j = 0; j < allSeries.length; j++){
            Series serie = (Series) allSeries[j];
            chart.removeSeries(serie);
        }

        // update the x- and y-axis - THIS IS NOT WORKING AND WHAT I'M TALKING ABOUT
        chartConfig.getXAxes().clear();
        chartConfig.getYAxes().clear();
        NumberXAxis xAxis = new NumberXAxis();
        xAxis.setTitle(new AxisTitle(xAxisTitle));
        xAxis.setStartOnTick(true);
        xAxis.setEndOnTick(true);
        xAxis.setShowLastLabel(true);
        LinkedHashSet<XAxis> xAxesSet = new LinkedHashSet<InvientChartsConfig.XAxis>();
        xAxesSet.add(xAxis);
        chartConfig.setXAxes(xAxesSet);
        NumberYAxis yAxis = new NumberYAxis();
        yAxis.setTitle(new AxisTitle(yAxisTitle));
        LinkedHashSet<YAxis> yAxesSet = new LinkedHashSet<InvientChartsConfig.YAxis>();
        yAxesSet.add(yAxis);
        chartConfig.setYAxes(yAxesSet);


        // add the new points - THIS IS WORKING AGAIN
        for (int i = 0; i < versionDates.size(); i++) {
            String versionDate = versionDates.get(i);
            List<double[]> versionValues = xAndYCoordinates.get(i);

            ScatterConfig versionScatterConfig = new ScatterConfig();
            XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Version " + (i + 1) + " - "
                    + versionDate, versionScatterConfig);
            series.setSeriesPoints(getPoints(series, versionValues));
            chart.addSeries(series);
        }
    }
```

As you can see, the removing and adding of points works perfectly fine, which I assume is because I'm working directly on the chart here, while I'm working on the chartConfig when I try to change the axes caption.

Could you please tell or show me how I can change the caption of the x- and y-Axis in an already existing chart (As described above)?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research I've come to the conclusion that there seems to be currently no way of changing the x- and yAxis caption dnymically, which works.

I found out that if you refresh the page, e.g. by pressing F5, the axes caption gets changed. I've tried implementing a refresher, but somehow the behaviour still didn't change.

So it looks like a bug (or software failure) for me.

My workaround which is doing the same is just removing the whole chart and then adding a completely new one with the new Axis-caption. This works perfectly fast and fine, but is a dirty solution in my eyes, since you have to add more lines of codes than necessary, as well as the logic is now basically more complicated then it should be.